# Confused with logical jump in this algebra exercise

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I can't seem to work out how my textbook got from the denominator($x^2 - x$) in the first line to the divisor below it ($x^2 +2x - 3$). Could anyone explain how they got from one to the other?

Thanks!

[image: textbook question]

Edit: 
A similar question which I *do* understand is here, for context:

[image]

Comment: which book is  it ? could be an error.

Comment: I'd notice that neither the divisor nor the dividend are the same as the fraction you are looking at in (c). Are you sure this division is not for a different part of the problem?

Comment: It's taken from the (electronic) "solution bank" for a textbook by Edexcel for UK A-level exams (core 4). Occasionally it has minor errors, but nothing like this! Usually of course I'm simply misunderstanding something. I'm pretty sure it's for the same part of the problem. The exercise is to turn the fraction into partial fractions, but first it needs to be made into a proper fraction, which is where the division comes in.

Comment: @Danny: This division is *not* related to the fraction in problem (c), period. It's not a logical jump, or a problem with your understanding. That's a quotient of two entirely different polynomials, not the ones involved in the fraction.

Comment: I have updated the question with part of the solution to the next question, which is the same in form but makes sense to me.

Comment: @Arturo OK thanks, I had hoped so!

Comment: @Dan It's surely a misprint - the fraction in (c) has no relation to the following long division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general consensus is that it is a misprint in the book.